# MySQL JOIN / GROUP one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, grouping, inner-join, one-to-many

I am kind of stuck..

I have two tables

```
mysql > EXPLAIN event;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL |                     |                             |
| extUrl      | varchar(192) | NO   |     |                     |                             |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

One event can have many

```
mysql> explain eventDate;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| category_id    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                             |
| event_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                             |
| location_id    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                             |
| name           | varchar(100) | NO   |     |                     |                             |
| eventDate      | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I'd like to query the event by `id`, with the `location_id` of the **next upcoming** `eventDate` and I am stuck how to form that query

I currently have this

```
 SELECT
      e.id,
      d.location_id,
      d.eventDate
 FROM
      event e
          INNER JOIN eventDate d ON d.event_id = e.id AND d.eventDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 WHERE
      e.id = 5107
 GROUP BY
      e.id
 ORDER BY
      d.eventDate ASC
```

Now this returns a result, but I GROUP BY event, so I am unsure how to ensure that really the next eventDate is selected. Also I didn't use any aggregate function ( group by one, aggregate many ), which doesn't seem to be a clean and clearly defined result requirement - MySQL is randomly selecting one of the eventDate rows now isn't it?

Comment: it will select any of the eventdates greater than, or equals to the current timestamp. Since you group it by ID, MySQL has no clue as to which row is more important to you. Hence it will select either the first or last one it encounters and not - as I believe you want it to - the next upcomming eventDate. You will have to expand your `WHERE` clause and/or put a `LIMIT` to it in order to select just 1

Comment: Yes, I want to have the next upcoming eventDate, I get one result row already due to the combination of `WHERE e.id = 5107` and `GROUP BY e.id` but I am not sure wether the `ORDER BY` clause kind of hints MySQL to select the next upcoming `d.eventDate`. There might be a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should always give you the first upcoming event:

```
 SELECT
      e.id,
      d.location_id,
      d.eventDate
 FROM
      event e
          INNER JOIN eventDate d ON d.event_id = e.id
 WHERE
      e.id = 5107
      AND
      d.id = (SELECT d1.id FROM eventDate d1 WHERE d1.event_id = 5107 AND d1.eventDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY d1.eventDate ASC LIMIT 1)
```

But the better way is to add `LIMIT 1` to your current query and removing the `GROUP BY`:

```
 SELECT
      e.id,
      d.location_id,
      d.eventDate
 FROM
      event e
          INNER JOIN eventDate d ON d.event_id = e.id AND d.eventDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 WHERE
      e.id = 5107
 ORDER BY
      d.eventDate ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it this also possible without the subquery and just adding the `LIMIT` to the first query (the one he posted) or am I missing something?

Comment: No you are right, i just added that one. To be honest that is the best way.

Comment: Solution one, I think, would be kind of inefficient, imagine a eventDate table with millions of rows, even if I would change this to `AND d.id = ( SELECT d1.id ... )`, solution two doen't solve the problem of "randomly - or not?" selected eventDate rows. I am getting one result row already ( e.id = xx + GROUP BY e.id )

Comment: ok, I see you changed both queries, so the comment above (partitially) is no longer valid. I'll think about your offers for a moment. Thank you! :)

Comment: In the second code snippet: if you remove the `group by` and keep the `order by` it will give you a list of all events that are beyond this moment ordered from closest to furthest from now. Limiting it to 1 will only show the first (so the next upcoming).

Comment: Yeah, I think solution two is fine for me - since I will never have a one-to millions-case but more likely a one-to-10 case

Comment: You are right about the first snippet being better when checking against id's, i changed it.